# Why would invoking IHTMLElement2.getBoundingClientRect() from inside BHO get several times slower when switching from C++ to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer, com, bho

I'm trying various options of creating a BHO for traversing HTML page DOM. One implementation uses C# and it's registered in registry with `ApartmentModel` set to `Both`. It goes like this:

1. retrieve `IWebBrowser2.Document`
2. obtain `IDocumentSelector` interface from document object
3. invoke `IDocumentSelector.querySelectorAll("*")` which yields a `IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection` reference
4. get `IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection.length`
5. run the for-loop in `0..length` range (`for(int index = 0; index < totalCount; index++)`),
6. inside loop iteration obtain each collection item using `IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection.item()`,
7. cast the collection item reference to `IHTMLElement2`,
8. obtain `IHTMLElement2.getClientBoundingRect()`

and it works rather fine, a page with about 1500 elements gets traversed in 200-300 milliseconds (loop duration is measured by reading `DateTime.UtcNow` before and after the loop and getting `TotalMilliseconds` from the readings difference).

Another implementation in done with Visual C++ and ATL. It does mostly the same as the C# version. `CComQIPtr` is used in place of casts. The loop is the same. It's also registered with `ApartmentModel` set to `Both`.

The C++ implementation traverses the very same page DOM in 40-60 milliseconds. Time is measured by reading `GetTickCount()` before and after the loop and getting the difference.

Then I exclude the step 8 from inside loop iteration - item is obtained and `IHTMLElement2` is obtained from it but `getClientBoundingRect()` is not invoked. After this change both implementations run in mostly the same time - 40-50 milliseconds.

This looks weird. Why would only `getClientBoundingRect()` be affected? What's so special in it that it slows down so much?

Comment: First, I'll just say benchmarking correctly is tough. I always use a `Stopwatch`, not `DateTime.UtcNow` and you need to run multiple iterations. The first time through, lazy loading is taking place for C# and is generally much slower than subsequent iterations. That being said, we're not going to be able to tell you why one is slower than the other without seeing the actual code for both. For example, saying "run the for-loop in 0..length range" could mean several things, some of which would be slower than others.

Comment: @itsme86 I clarified how the loop header is organized.

Comment: @itsme86 The results are mostly the same with `Stopwatch`.

Comment: Do you have a reproducing sample (with html in question)?

Comment: Can you please inform us, which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test? On which OS build you are producing this issue? If possible, you can you share both C# and C++ code example? We can try to test the issue and check for the issue.

Comment: @SimonMourier No, I cannot invest time in producing a minimal working sample of a BHO before I know that the thing possibly works with reasonable performance.

Comment: Is, in general, pure C/C++ COM call faster than C# COM call? Yes, for example https://pastebin.com/raw/kWirNfXN (.NET framework) but there's not only the call itself, there can be everything that's around (like parameters, allocations, etc.). That wouldn't necessarily explain a 5x faster, but that possible. As soon as you start doing other things (connecting to internet, database, whatever) these pure numbers (~6M calls per second in C#) may become insignificant, depends on context. Difficult to say w/o some reproducing code.